# Adding dynamic checkboxes with label with span

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add dynamic content to my asp.net page.

These contents should look like this:

```
<li>
     <span class="textDropdown">Text1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" runat="server"/>
      <label for="1"></label>
</li>
```

#### What I have tried

```
private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
        {
            return string.Format("<li><span class=\"textDropdown\">{0}</span><input runat=\"server\" id=\"{1}\" value=\"{0}\" type=\"checkbox\"><label for=\"{1}\"></label></li>", checkBoxText, checkBoxText + "dropdownID");
        }
```

I made that function and it really works and adding the content. but It seems that this way is not good because I need to have objects in my c# codes in order to add them to my update panel.

Could you tell me please how to add that content using c# objects not strings (like my way).

Answer (score 1):

- 1.You can do that with Format also
- 2.Other way Around

---

in your `CreateCheckbox` function do this

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");                    
panelWrapper.Controls.Add(li);

var checkbox = new CheckBox();

checkbox.ID = "chk" + exemptionId;
li.Controls.Add(checkbox);
```

where `panelWrapper` would be a  `Panel`

- 3.here you can assign some Property to your Checkbox

Comment: In this way you have added the checkbox. I already knows that. my problem is adding the `li` which has to contain the checkbox, the label and the span. could u help please?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, please could you add the span and the label? I will try myself but in case I faild